# Not works well "react-native run-ios" or "react-native run-android" command from running project by Run/Debug configuration in WebStorm 2018.2

Tags: react-native, webstorm

When I run a React-Native project after configure Run/Debug Configuration, Metro Bundler runs OK and after that freezing. So I stopped the Metro Bundler, I got an error message.

First, I set Run/Debug configuration like this picture

[image: Run/Debug Configuration named RN-IOS]

Second, I ran RN-IOS and stopped Metro Bundler myself because of it did not work after the process

[image: Error screen and message]

I've tried the below:

1. Removed all Node and related directories manually in my machine and reinstalled, not working.
2. Removed `.idea` directory from the project was not working.
3. Create empty project using WebStorm and running was not working.
4. Searched JetBrains Issue Tracker but could not find any solution.

Please, let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running/debugging with *React Native 0.57+* doesn't work; [WEB-34895](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34895) is fixed in upcoming WebStorm 2018.3.
For previous versions, the only workarpound is starting the bundler externally (`react-native start`) and removing corresponding *before launch* task from *React Native* run configuration.